# 'Sub'-account merge with new account

Tags: support, merge-accounts

Is it possible to 'merge' only a site account (part of a network account) into a new account **whilst preserving all the other site accounts part of the network account?**

For the avoidance of doubt, let's say there are two existing 'accounts' set-up like:

- Main SE Account

  - Main Site-1 Account
  - Main Site-2 Account
  - Main Site-3 Account
- New SE account

  - New Site-3 Account

Can a merge take place that restructures the accounts to be like:

- Main SE Account

  - Main Site-1 Account
  - Main Site-2 Account
  - <strike>Main Site-3 Account</strike>
- New SE account

  - Main Site-3 Account *merged into* New Site-3 Account

I have reviewed posts relating to merging accounts but I could not see anything explicitly discussing the merging of *only* a specific site account not a whole network account (in comparison to account deletion, where there is an explicit statement that a site-account can be deleted without affecting the rest of the SE account - this is my fallback option). Apologies if I missed it.

My ultimate hope is to create a break between professional/personal sites ;)

Comment: I think that is something you should use the [contact form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) for :)